# Zip every file in all folders and subfolders to a separate zip file

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I have this folder structure:

```
Backup
    Database1
        database11.bak
        database12.bak
    Database2
        Backup21
            database211.bak
            database212.bak
        Backup22
            Backup223
                database2231.bak
...
```

I need to zip every file in all folders and subfolders to a separate zip file in their original folder. The result should be:

```
Backup
    Database1
        database11.7z
        database12.7z
    Database2
        Backup21
            database211.7z
            database212.7z
        Backup22
            Back223
                database2231.7z
...
```

So far I come up with this. I will zip all files in a folder

FOR %%i IN (%folderToArchive%*.bak) DO 7z.exe a "%folderToArchive%\%%~ni.7z" "%%i"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a trial: launch it from the top level folder

```
FOR /r %%i IN ("*.bak") DO 7z.exe a "%%~dpni.7z" "%%i"
```